# Format currency in ASP.NET 5 C#

Tags: c#, format, currency

```html
@model IQueryable<Product>

@foreach (var p in Model )
{
        <div>
            <h3>@p.Name</h3>
            @p.Description
            <h4>@p.Price.ToString("C", new CultureInfo("us-US"))</h4>
        </div>
}
```

I would like to express the currency format on my own.

Like USD $ 285.00

I tried with `CurrencyPositivePattern`, but failed all.

In `index.cshtml` file, how can I do this?

thank you.

Comment: Please review [ask] and [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: sorry about your comment, i replaced image into code. But i've already searched a long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<h4>USD $ @p.Price.ToString("n2")</h4>
```

This will output `USD $` first, and then take the `Price` value and format it to 2 digits after the decimal point, numerically.

See [this official MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings) for more details on how to properly format numeric values, and all the options you have to do so.